# How to change textbox width MVC4 Bootstrap 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can somebody help me out on how to change width of Edit box in following code? I tried everything but stubborn edit box wont change its width.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the default `site.css` file (which includes `input,select,textarea { max-width: 280px; }`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this- Include style inside html attributes.

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style="width: 10px" } })
```

Comment: Can you remove the style from html attribute and in your .css file add `.form-control { width: 100px;}`, can you try this

Comment: It seems working. But somehow it messes with TextArea width which becomes 100% to its containing division.

Comment: Only first time i see set width. When i refresh browser, width goes back to default value.

Comment: Can you inspect the textbox if some other style is over riding it ?

Comment: Hi ISHIDA, Thank you for your help on this. Actually browser was not updating site.css where i changed max width for textarea, input and textbox. Now it is working.

Comment: Cool. Is width working now ? Do I need to update my answer ?